# Sending an EOF to exit out of a multi line read causes an exception when seeking input for another variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, eof, eofexception

If I have the following Python code:

```
keyphrase = sys.stdin.read()
print(keyphrase)
domain = input()
print(domain)
```

I run it as follows:

```
/Users/me/bin/python /Users/me/PycharmProjects/pem_formatter/test_code.py
Please enter a key:
Key line 1
Key line 2
Key line 3
^D
Key line 1
Key line 2
Key line 3

Please enter a domain:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/pem_formatter/test_code.py", line 8, in <module>
    domain = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I tried using a try/except as follows:

```
try:
    print('Please enter a key:')
    keyphrase = sys.stdin.read()
    print(keyphrase)
except EOFError as error:
    print('EOF Error')
```

but it made little difference:

```
/Users/me/bin/python /Users/me/PycharmProjects/pem_formatter/test_code.py
Please enter a key:
Key line 1
Key line 2
Key line 3
^D
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/pem_formatter/test_code.py", line 12, in <module>
    domain = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Key line 1
Key line 2
Key line 3

Please enter a domain:

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What do I do in scenarios where I may want to take a multi line input for one variable and a single line for another?

Comment: Thanks @jordanm. I actually came across that. I just can't help feel there must be a better way to do this. I thought `sys.stdin.read()` be a solution but having to Ctrl-D is causing issues.

Comment: That's because Ctrl-D sends EOF and closes stdin.